# ReflectionClass keeps returning className does not exist

Tags: php, reflection, php-7, php-7.2

What am trying to do is use `scandir()` to scan a directory and get all the files there, then use the `ReflectionClass` to read or access the class.

I was able to get all the files in the directory and assigned it to an array but was unable to read or access the `properties` and the `methods` using the `\ReflectionClass` as it keeps returning

> Class App\Controllers\AtController does not exist

This is the code I have so far

```
// The directory to scan and assign it to a variable
$classControllers = scandir($cur_dir . '/app/Controllers');

// Change to the ReflectionClass to access
chdir($cur_dir . '/app/Controllers/');

// Dump the $classControllers to see if it truly scan the directory
var_dump($classControllers);

$control = '';

// Loop over the $classControllers
foreach($classControllers as $classController){
    if($classController != "." && $classController != "..")
    {
        $classController = str_ireplace(".php", "", $classController);
        echo $classController . PHP_EOL;

        // Use ReflectionClass to read the class name, methods and properties of each class.
        $controllers = new \ReflectionClass("App\\Controllers\\$classController")#App\Controllers is the namespace of the files in the directory;

        $controller = $controllers->getName();
        $control = substr($controller, 12);
        $control = ucfirst($control);
        $routeScript .= "\t$control" . "," . PHP_EOL; 
    }
}
```

NB: `new \ReflectionClass("App\\Controllers\\$classController"); #App\Controllers is the namespace of the files in the directory`

Comment: Do you use autoloading to load the classes?

Comment: Yes, I use autoloading to load it

Comment: How did you setup the autoloading?

Comment: Try to add `include_once $classController;` before the line `$classController = str_ireplace(".php", "", $classController);` and see.

Comment: @KoalaYeung I set up the autoloading using the composer.json

Comment: The code you shown does not include the `autoload` setup in the composer.json nor the `require 'vendor/autoload.php` statement. It is hard to examine if the autoloading is setup correctly.

Comment: This issue, to my experience, usually comes from 2 sources: (1) the incorrect setup of autoloading; and (2) typo in the class name or namespace in the class file. Please check both.

Comment: Also, what is this supposed to do: `$control = substr($controller, 12);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue, to my experience, usually comes from 2 sources:

1. the incorrect setup of autoloading; and
2. typo in the class name or namespace in the class file.

If it is the 1st issue, adding a simple line in your file would fix the issue:

```php
<?php

$cur_dir = __DIR__;

// The directory to scan and assign it to a variable
$classControllers = scandir($cur_dir . '/app/Controllers');

// Change to the ReflectionClass to access
chdir($cur_dir . '/app/Controllers/');

// Dump the $classControllers to see if it truly scan the directory
var_dump($classControllers);

$control = '';
$routeScript = '';

// Loop over the $classControllers
foreach($classControllers as $classController){
    if($classController != "." && $classController != "..")
    {
        include_once $classController; // <-- this line
        $classController = str_ireplace(".php", "", $classController);
        echo $classController . PHP_EOL;

        // Use ReflectionClass to read the class name, methods and properties of each class.
        $controllers = new \ReflectionClass("App\\Controllers\\$classController"); #App\Controllers is the namespace of the files in the directory;

        $controller = $controllers->getName();
        $control = substr($controller, 12);
        $control = ucfirst($control);
        $routeScript .= "\t$control" . "," . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Please also check the second issue. Both namespace and class name are case sensitive. It is easy to have typo for both of them:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class AtController {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Koala Yeung for saving my day. The issue was the 1st case(Incorrect setup of autoloading). I never include the app directory in composer.json file